# how to run a nested loop in lambda, where one value is coming from dictionary with multiple values for one key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to create a new column in dataframe using lambda in python, in which I have to run a loop on dict having multiple values for a key and map it with other variable on which loop is running for each value in dict if 2 values are being assigned to a key.

below is the code I wrote but was not able to map with each dict value but a value pair as whole

`acc['metric'] = acc.apply(lambda x: f'{kind}.{squ.units}.{inv}.{self.name}.{x.label}', axis=1)`

so here squ is having key value pair in which units key have multiple values at a point.

metric column output is something like -

```
day.{'cde','abc'}.dev.bde.ops
day.{'test','rmp'}.sand.sab.ops
```

but i want output to be -

```
day.cde.dev.bde.ops
day.abc.dev.bde.ops
day.test.sand.sab.ops
day.rmp.sand.sab.ops
```

can someone please suggest how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the value of `squ.units`, return a list then [explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on column `metric`.

```py
acc['metric'] = acc.apply(lambda x: [f'{kind}.{unit}.{inv}.{self.name}.{x.label}' for unit in squ.units], axis=1)

acc_ = acc.explode('metric')
```

Comment: i don't want to get this output day.cde.abc.dev.bde.ops but day.cde.dev.bde.ops and day.abc.dev.bde.ops. squ is a dict type and units is key